# Tag decorations appear in hidden coments

Tags: bug, design

This is pretty self explanatory.

Here, a hidden comment:

> We have a [tag](/questions/tagged/tag) here.

You can see the tag, albeit almost unreadable, depending on your constrast/color settings, even without revealing the text.